# Spring Data JPA with Transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I am developing an application using Spring Data JPA with Transactions. Although the version of Spring I'm on (4.0.0) is able to use JavaConfig, I prefer to stick with XML.

**I have this config:**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

<jpa:repositories base-package="repo"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="service" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/staffing?transformedBitIsBoolean=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="vivupdip1`"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="model"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

**My single (so far) repository is this:**

```
package repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import model.Volunteer;

public interface VolunteerRepo extends JpaRepository<Volunteer, Integer> {
}
```

I also have a Service interface in the `service` package:

```
public interface VolunteerService {
  public List<Volunteer> findAll();
}
```

**and the implementation:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class VolunteerServiceImpl implements VolunteerService {

    @Autowired VolunteerRepo repo;

    public List<Volunteer> findAll() {
      return repo.findAll();
    }

}
```

**called from a `Controller` in the `controller` package:**

```
@RestController
public class VolunteerController {

  @Autowired VolunteerService vs;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/volunteers")
  List<Volunteer> getVolunteers() {
    return vs.findAll();
  }
}
```

The `Volunteer` domain object is quite complex and is related to various other domain objects.

When I issue the correct request in the browser, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Volunteer.volunteerSessions, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->model.Volunteer["sessions"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Volunteer.volunteerSessions, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->model.Volunteer["sessions"])
```

which, as far as I understand, is moaning about not having a session, which (I think) can be fixed by configuring transactions properly. But, my attempt as configuring transactions seems not to be correct, but I cannot work out why.

Comment: Do you have `volunteerSessions` instance field mapped as `oneToMany` with LAZY loading in the `Volunteer` class. If so, enable  EAGER loading of this and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errormessage stating that there is no session available is preceded by:

```
Could not write JSON
```

This tells you that **the proxy was accessed when attempting to serialize the object into JSON.** This is happening in your `RestController`, which indeed is not transactional, so has no session bound, and that is why the lazy-loading failed.

Possible solutions are:

- Add a DAO layer and transform your DB objects into simple java POJOs when returning from your `VolunteerServiceImpl`
- You can try to annotate your controller as @Transactional
- You might want to consider switching off lazyloading if you know that you will always need that "volunteer" data because you are returning in a JSON response

Comment: Excellent answer - that a good clear explanation, such appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have closed the session before your bean have been serialized to JSON. This is typical behavior for CRUD applications that close the session after each transactional operation. Because it happens in the service layer you can't access objects that designed for lazy initialization and hence aren't loaded by the Hibernate.  The solution is either you exclude these lazy properties or if you need them to initialize keep the session open during serialization. You can achive this by implementing [Open Session In View](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) pattern.

> A common issue in a typical (web-)application is the rendering of the view, after the main logic of the action has been completed, and therefore, the Hibernate Session has already been closed and the database transaction has ended. If you access detached objects that have been loaded in the Session inside your JSP (or any other view rendering mechanism), you might hit an unloaded collection or a proxy that isn't initialized. The exception you get is: LazyInitializationException: Session has been closed (or a very similar message). Of course, this is to be expected, after all you already ended your unit of work.
>
> A first solution would be to open another unit of work for rendering the view. This can easily be done but is usually not the right approach. Rendering the view for a completed action is supposed to be inside the first unit of work, not a separate one. The solution, in two-tiered systems, with the action execution, data access through the Session, and the rendering of the view all in the same virtual machine, is to keep the Session open until the view has been rendered.